# Is there a generic way to reference the current project?

Tags: vb.net

I need to pass a form to a sub. If my project is called Project1 and contains a form called Form1, I do this as follows:

```
Public Sub ProcessForm(ByRef myForm As Project1.Form1)
etc etc
```

Is there a generic way to refer to the current project - Project1 - so that I could copy the code to other projects, without having to change the reference to the project?

I was thinking of something like `My.Project`, so that I could refer to `My.Project.Form1`, but cannot see how to do this.

Am using VS 2010.

Comment: Put all the forms in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with

```
Namespace.Class
```

ie, if your project namespace is MyProjectName and the class is form1. you need

```
MyProjectName.form1
```

Comment: Thank you @bizzehdee. My code already works using `Project1.Form1`, but I hoped to replace this with a generic term for the current project.

Comment: there isnt any such thing in vb.net or c# as the project name is actually a namespace and as such, part of the scope of the code and part of the naming system, there isnt another way of referencing code within a namespace other than using the namespace

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you cannot do exactly as asked, so your best option for this example is:

```
Public Sub ProcessForm(ByRef myForm As Form1)
```

letting the default namespace specify which `Form1` you mean.